# when i am trying to run the pig + cassandra error shows up? help required please

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

[root@SudeepMangu pig]# bin/pig_cassandra -x local example-script.pig

Using /home/sudeep/pig-0.9.2/pig-0.9.2-withouthadoop.jar.
2013-05-30 14:22:20,007 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/sudeep/apache-cassandra-1.2.5-src/examples/pig/pig_1369903940005.log
2013-05-30 14:22:20,133 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///

2013-05-30 14:22:20,668 [main] ****ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt*** -* **ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig., , org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]**

Answer (score 1):

The JAR that contains the CassandraStorage UDF is not in your classpath.  You need to register it in your script like:

```
REGISTER /path/to/jar;
```

Then you will be able to use it.